# Manager for Google Shared Drive has limited access to files on Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm the manager of a google shared drive. I have code that produces files on the drive automatically. When I run the code, I have full access to the produced files. For example, I can unhide the hidden sheets. However, When other users run the code, I DO NOT have full access to the produced files. For example, I CANNOT then unhide the hidden sheets.

My understanding of shared drives is that the Managers have full access to everything. Clearly, I'm missing something.

Advice and insight appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem with some spreadsheets created by me and moved into a Shared Drive: I'm able to restore versions from the version history but the other Shared Drive managers aren't. 

Ask your domain admin to send a support ticket to Google Workspace support.

Comment: Can you share a minimum reproducible example?
Managers indeed have full access to files within a share drive, but I suspect that we might have a permissions-related issue as the root cause

Comment: Could you provide us the screenshot of the permissions of the Google Sheet? Also, when you tried to hide the sheet does it have multiple sheets (tab)?

Comment: All good comments. I didn't realize the drive could have more than one manager. I'm new to shared drives. Providing manager access to the other user(s) fixed the problem. Apparently, when a new file is created within the shared drive, the permissions default to the user's role when that the file is created, even if the content manager is using and has full permissions within the sheet and code environment used to create the new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm creating this community Wiki for further reference since the issue was solved in the comments. The problem was related to the [access levels](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554) inside the Share Drive. The fix to the problem was to [add other managers](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310249?hl=en#1.2:%7E:text=%E2%9C%94-,Add%20members%20and%20set%20access%20levels,-%3A) to Share Drive as mentioned by the community in the comments.

**Reference:**

- [Shared drives access levels.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554)
- [Set up a shared drive.](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310249?hl=en#1.2)